# Why does Cucumber drop tables if schema.rb is not present?

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, cucumber

I have a Rails 4 app that uses an external DB I don't control. So there is no schema or migration. Anyway, I create a model and use db setting the table_name in the model.

When I run cucumber it drops the db tables!?
Any idea why and how to avoid it?

```
$ bundle exec cucumber

Running via Spring preloader in process 18865

.../db/schema.rb doesn't exist yet. Run `rake 
db:migrate` to create it, then try again. If you do not intend to use a 
database, you should instead alter 
.../config/application.rb to limit the frameworks that 
will be loaded.
```

After that the db is empty, no tables.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should still be able to dump your schema locally if ActiveRecord is connecting to the db.

```
rake db:schema:dump
```

Comment: well, basically you mean I should create the schema.rb. That fix the problem but why I should do it if I can run the app without it, even I'm able to write in the db through the model.
you know what I mean?, it's strange that schema is a requirement for cucumber and not for rails itself.

Comment: it's not strange if the test database is being created by the test framework.